# Glassfish needs restart after deploy with ICEFaces

Tags: glassfish, icefaces

i have a strange problem. I have an ICEFaces(1.8.2) + Facelets application im working on and every time i make a change to it and deploy i must restart Glassfish(2.1.1) else i get a "java.lang.ClassCastException" on my entities. The error message is :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: za.co.africanpulse.rms.frontend.domain.Menuheader cannot be cast to za.co.africanpulse.rms.frontend.domain.Menuheader

If i restart Glassfish as said above all is ok... but this is getting kinda irratating. I dont quite know what exactly you would like me to post so that my problem is easier identified / understood. Anyways any help will be most appreciated.

Many many thanks

Comment: Glad to see that you found a solution.  You may want to take a couple minutes to post it as a formal answer, so other folks will not have to learn the same knowledge 'the hard way'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the web.xml servlet version is below 2.5 and jsf is still at 1.1 specified in the faces-config.xml then strange persistence related issues will arise. In my case entities could not be cast to themselves..???

After changing servlet version and jsf version i could successfully inject EntityManagers into my DAOs...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably open an issue with the GlassFish project: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues.

StackOverflow isn't really designed to be a bug reporting/analysis tool.

That said... someone might have run into this and you could 'Get Lucky'...

Edit 1:

For example, this query: http://www.google.com/search?q=glassfish+icefaces+facelet+classcastexception

Netted this hit: http://seamframework.org/Community/HelpOnSeam220ICEfaces181AndGlassfish21

which looks like it may be useful.

Comment: its got to do with servlet version being below 2.5 and jsf being on 1.1. Once upgrading jsf to 1.2 and servlet version in web.xml to 2.5, i can inject entityManagers now.

thanks